# Installing steam to an SD card?

Tags: steam

I have a chromebook. I installed crouton and unity. I cannot install steam to the main hardrive because it only has 3.2 gigs of memory left. I mounted a micro sd card to my chromebook and one of my friends told me to use "symlink" to install it to the sd card. I would really like some help on how to install it to the sd card, 'cause I have no idea what to do. I am new to linux.

Comment: I'll just inform you now, you aren't going to have great performance on a microsd. Loading will take a long time, and the microSD will fail if you play games that download a lot (TF2, garry's mod, etc) or write a lot.

Comment: I'm not going to play those types of games. I just wanna play some small games, like avgn adventures, undertale, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing this, which again, I warned about the lack of life on the SD card in the comments, you are warned again.

**Install steam to your hard-drive.** Yes I know you only have 3.2GB left, it won't stay on the drive, but get it on there initially. It should only take 1-2 GB of space.

**Move the steam directory**, located at `~/.local/share/Steam`, onto the drive. You can do this either in the terminal, `mv ~/.local/share/Steam /media/USER/FLASHDRIVE/`, or through a file manager. You will have to maybe do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show the hidden `.local` folder.

**Make the symbolic link** through a terminal by running `ln -s /media/USER/FLASHDRIVE/.steam ~/.local/share/Steam`. This creates a link TO `/media/USER/FLASHDRIVE/.steam` named/located at `~/.local/share/Steam`. The paths will need to be correct, <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion is your friend.

**Test run steam** and install some games, you should start seeing the size of the drive go down when adding games, and your system will probably be at 3 gigs by the end of this (for a few application files in root for steam to run properly).

Note that this will only work if the drive is mounted to the same place every time it is connected. Also, don't attempt to start steam without the flashdrive in...I'm not sure what that would do.

---

An alternate way of doing this would be to install steam on your computer like normal, but setup, download, and play games from a different directory (your microsd drive). Steam itself isn't that large, and wouldn't take up more than a gig (I think). Just, when you install/download games, change the desination directory to the drive.

Comment: Hello. When I open steam to downloads the update, I get an error saying I need at lease 250MB is space free to update.

Comment: Is that before or after you move the steam directory to the microsd? If it's before, you might try moving some other large files that you have onto the microsd before you install steam. One other option is to create the partition and actually link the folder before there is anything in the folder, then install Steam. It might be happy with it and install its components directly to the microsd.